# Finding by an easy way the eigenvalues of the matrix $P$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any easy way to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix?

$P:=$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 8 & 2 & 0\\
-1 & -5 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 8 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}

I have checked out the solution by a calculator but I would like to no if there is an easy way to find the eigenvalues of the matrix P. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You directly see that $(0,0,0,1)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $2$. Then you only have to calculate the eigenvalues of the upper left $(3 \times 3)$ block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what kind of solution you're looking for but thought it still might help to just post the "straight forward" way here by calculating the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$:

\begin{align*}
p(x) &= \begin{vmatrix}
1 - x & 8 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & -5 -x & -1 & 0 \\
2 & 8 & 1 -x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2-x 
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= (2-x) \cdot \begin{vmatrix}
1 - x & 8 & 2  \\
-1 & -5 -x & -1  \\
2 & 8 & 1 -x  
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= (2-x) \cdot \begin{vmatrix}
3 - x & 16 & 3-x  \\
-1 & -5 -x & -1  \\
2 & 8 & 1 -x  
\end{vmatrix} \tag{Adding the 3. row to the 1. one.} \\
&= (2-x) \cdot \begin{vmatrix}
3 - x & 16 & 0  \\
-1 & -5 -x & 0  \\
2 & 8 &  - 1 -x  
\end{vmatrix} \tag{Subtracting the 1. column from the 3. one.} \\
&= (2-x) \cdot (-1 - x) \cdot \begin{vmatrix}
3 - x & 16  \\
-1 & -5 -x  
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= (2-x) \cdot (-1 - x) \cdot ((3-x)(-5-x)+16) \\
&= (2-x) \cdot (-1 - x) \cdot (x^2 + 2x -15 +16) \\
&= (2-x) \cdot (- 1 - x)^3
\end{align*}
So, the eigenvalues are $2$ with (algebraic) multiplicity $1$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $3$.

Comment: and is this matrix diagonalisable? I mean among the real or complex numbers. I have already checked out by using a calculator that it's not real diagonalisable, but can I show it without calculating a huge amount? What about the complex numbers?

Comment: @Herrpeter It is simple (you don't even need paper) to calculate the nullity of $A+I$, it's $2$ and so the matrix is not diagonalisable.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by $A$ ? the matrix above?